# Android: Quickblox localview behind the back of remoteview

Tags: android, quickblox, quickblox-android

I use `quickblox` for call video

This is my `xml` :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignWithParentIfMissing="true"
    android:background="#000"
    tools:context="com.dev.trueme.VideoCallActivity">

    <com.quickblox.videochat.webrtc.view.QBRTCSurfaceView
        android:id="@+id/opponentView"
        android:layout_width="310dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignWithParentIfMissing="true" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/oppLayout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="false"
        android:background="#33000000">

        <com.quickblox.videochat.webrtc.view.QBRTCSurfaceView
            android:id="@+id/localView"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="120dp"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="false"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="false"
            android:layout_alignWithParentIfMissing="false" />
    </FrameLayout>
```

On receive remote video track, `localview` behind back `opponentView` and reorder automatic

Other element work correct, just `localView` reorder after on receive video remote

Comment: Can help me anyone ?

Comment: Did you reproduce this issue on QuickBlox's sample? Please review theirs code and search mistakes in own code.